# Visibility of custom Flowgear Nodes

Tags: flowgear

If I develop a custom node, does it need to be published for other developers on the site to see it and use it in workflows they build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If other developers need access to a Node that you published, and they either need Node Publisher permission on the account that you published the Node under, or you need to request Flowgear to review the Node and make it public.